# Combine multiple event sources into one IObservable with Rx

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, system.reactive

This is a question about how to use Reactive Extensions (Rx) in a specific event-related scenario.

- The aim is to take a number of classes that trigger some event
- And congregate them into one `IObservable` that can be subscribed to by any clients (unaware of the event classes).
- Note the events of interest use subclassed `EventArgs`

### Some Custom EventArgs

```
public class HappenedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    internal bool IsBadNotGood;
}
```

### Many Separate Classes Where Happened Events Occur

```
public class EventSourceA : IEventSource {

    public event HappenedEventHandler Happened;
    private void OnHappened(HappenedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Happened != null)
            Happened(this, e);
    }
    // And then this class calls OnHappened(e) whenever it decides to ...
}

public class EventSourceB : IEventSource {

    public event HappenedEventHandler Happened;
    private void OnHappened(HappenedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Happened != null)
            Happened(this, e);
    }
    // And then this class also calls OnHappened(e) at times ...
}

public interface IEventSource
{
    event HappenedEventHandler Happened;
}

public delegate void HappenedEventHandler(object sender, HappenedEventArgs e);
```

### How to Congregate All Those Events and Expose a United Event Front

```
public class Pooler{

    private IObservable<X> _pool;

    public IObservable<X> Subscribe(){
        return _pool;        
    }

    public void Register(IEventSource item)
    {
        // How to take item.Happened and inject/bind it into _pool here?
    }        

    internal void Unregister(IEventSource item)
    {
        // Disconnect item.Happened from _pool
    }

    public Pooler(){
        // Instantiate _pool to whatever is best?
        // _pool = ...
    }

 }
```

### A Subscriber Who Doesnt Know Anything About EventSources Directly

```
 static void Try() {
     var pooler = new Pooler();
     pooler.Subscribe().Subscribe(e =>
            {
                 // Do something with events here, as they arrive
            }
     );
     // ....
     // Wherever whenever:
     AddEventSources(pooler);
 }

 static void AddEventSources(Pooler pooler){
     var eventSourceA = new EventSourceA();
     pooler.Register(eventSourceA);
     var eventSourceB = new EventSourceB();
     pooler.Register(eventSourceB);     
 }
```

Comment: +1 for very well written question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What the Rx library tries to provide are ways of handling situations such as these without having to create a bunch of classes/methods that manually propagate observables.

Let's say you had a class with an event:

```
public class EventedClass
{
    public event Action<EventArgs> Event;
}
```

And an enumerable of those instances `IEnumerable<EventedClass> objects`,
you can use LINQ to project observables out of those classes, combine them with `Observable.Merge` which will give you the combined sequential output of those events.

```
Observable.Merge(
    objects.Select(
        o => Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(
            handler => o.Event += handler,
            handler => o.Event -= handler
        )
)).Subscribe(args => 
{ 
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks! My compiler does not like += handler and -= handler though, even though i specify <HappenedEventArgs> - im guessing it is due to having my events declared as `public event HappenedEventHandler Happened; public delegate void HappenedEventHandler(object sender, HappenedEventArgs e);` I dont know what `FromEvent` syntax i need to use to get that to work?

Comment: There's another overload  `Observable.FromEvent<TDelegate, TEventArgs>` which allows you to specify the type of delegate for handler. Without it, the default handler is `Action<EventArgs>`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are doing something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083357/adding-an-observable-sequence-after-subscription/8087911#8087911).  Basically, you want to use a subject as your `_pool` variable and have it subscribe and unsubscribe to the different event sources in Register and Unregister.   To unregister a source, you will need to keep the disposables you got in the call to Register.  Also, I would consider making `Pooler` implement `IObservable` directly and just forward `Subscribe` to the `_pool` variable.

```
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

public class Pooler 
    : IObservable<HappenedEventArgs>, 
      IDisposable
{

    void Dispose()
    {
        if (_pool != null) _pool.Dispose();
        if (_sourceSubs != null)
        {
            foreach (var d in _sourceSubs.Values)
            {
                d.Dispose();
            }
            _sourceSubs.Clear();
        }
    }

    private Subject<HappenedEventArgs> _pool = new Subject<HappenedEventArgs>();
    private Dictionary<IEventSource, IDisposable> _sourceSubs = new Dictionary<IEventSource, IDisposable>();

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<HappenedEventArgs> observer)
    {
        return _pool.Subscribe(observer);
    }

    public void Register(IEventSource item)
    {
        if (_sourceSubs.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            return; //already registered
        }
        else
        {
            _sourceSubs.Add(item,
                            Observable.FromEventPattern((EventHandler<HappenedEventArgs> h) => item.Happened += h,
                                                        h => item.Happened -= h)
                                      .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
                                      .Subscribe(_pool));
        }
    }

    internal void Unregister(IEventSource item)
    {
        IDisposable disp = null;
        if (_sourceSubs.TryGetValue(item, out disp))
        {
            _sourceSubs.Remove(item);
            disp.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you will need to implement `IDisposable` to ensure that you can clean up all the event subscriptions when you are done with the `Pooler`.

Comment: i really like your answer, and the specificity and extras that Asti did not have, but Asti was first, so i awarded him the answer ...