# How to merge 2 observables without breaking current subscriptions?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

I want to have a observable to which I could subscribe with the ability to merge other observables in runtime.

I have thought of using the `Observable.Merge` method, but it returns a **new** observable sequence.

so if I have:

```
var merged = observable1.Merge(observable2);
```

that will not allow me to dynamically merge more sequences. I would have to create and subscribe again to the newly created sequence.

Is there any way to merge and keep the current subscriptions untouched?

Comment: look at the [`Subjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.subjects(v=vs.103).aspx) classes ;) - you can just subscribe them to more observables on the fly - I guess the [`Subject<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173(v=vs.103).aspx) will do just fine in most cases

Comment: This looks like a nice way of doing it http://stackoverflow.com/a/8098541/1239433